# Map Two Identical tables ( same schema...) to same entity in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have table1 and table2 that have the same schema... and I want to have only one entity rather than two ( since the fields will be the same).
How would I achieve that in hibernate with XML mapping.
So my goal is when I m querying in the DAO, how would it know which table to pull from if both tables are mapped to the same entity.

I m trying to Not create a parent class and then two subclasses.

Thanks

Comment: More importantly, which table would it write to?

Comment: correct, I want to be able to read and write to two tables, use two mapping files and only one class. not sure if it is even possible. but said let me ask the experts in StackOverflow and see if it is possible to specify the table at the DAO level or something similar.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505866/how-to-map-one-class-to-different-tables-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I looked at those questions before. but they all use inheritence. I m trying to not use inheritence and no annotation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer.  i have answered this question several times on stackoverflow.

---

To map two identical tables onto one entity class, you need to use the `entity-name` property of Hibernate or NHibernate.

Documentation is here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-entityname

For example, to map a single class Order to Order and OrderHistory tables, you create a mapping file that maps the order class to the two tables using new `entity-names` (`Order` and `OrderHistory`) like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
   <class name="DomainModel.Order, DomainModel"
   table="Orders" entity-name="Order">`  
     <id name="_id" access="field" column="OrderId">
         <generator class="assigned"/>
     </id>
    <property name= ...>
</class>
<class name="DomainModel.Order, DomainModel"
 table="OrderHistories" entity-name="OrderHistory">
     <id name="_id" access="field" column="OrderId">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
     </id>
    <property name= ...>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then depending on the type of entity you need, you simply call the appropriate Session methods as:

```
_session.Save("Order", myOrder)
```

or

```
_session.Save("OrderHistory", myOrder)
```

Simple, isn't ?

In general `entity-name` must replace class name in all Hibernate calls.

Comment: What if I don't call the save method and entities are persisted on transaction commit ? I mean that I would like to persist to different tables depending to which parent entity the order class belongs.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with annotations?

Comment: Found that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505866/how-to-map-one-class-to-different-tables-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations