# Is it possible to provide more than one mapping for a particular persistent class?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a scenario where i have the same table columns but with different names like `TicketBooking` and `TicketBookingHistory`. I have a single pojo class `TicketBooking`. Is it possible to provide more than one mapping for this persistent class that is one for `TicketBooking` and one for `TicketBookingHistory` ? If so how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<class name="TicketBooking" table="TicketBooking"
        entity-name="TicketBooking">

</class>

<class name="TicketBooking" table="TicketBookingHistory"
        entity-name="TicketBookingHistory">
    ...
</class>
```

**This feature is not supported in Annotations.**

I think your should have look in [Mapping a class more than once](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-entityname).
The same question can be found in [Map Two Identical tables ( same schema...) to same entity in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997950/map-two-identical-tables-same-schema-to-same-entity-in-hibernate).

But all of these are used with xml mapping.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with xml mappings.  Nno way to achieve this with annotations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `entity-name` attribute of class mapping. Check the [documentation here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class) of the same.

To quote the documentation:

```
entity-name (optional - defaults to the class name): Hibernate3 allows a class to be mapped 
multiple times, potentially to different tables
```

Here is [another example](http://coderoony.blogspot.in/2008/12/mapping-class-multiple-times-in.html) of the same use case.