# Hibernate - Query multiple tables with one hibernate-mapping

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, mapping, hbm

I do have a hibernate mapping which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="org.lwl.anlei.bl.model.imp">  

   <class name="PersonFo">
     <id name="id" type="integer"/>     
     <property name="name" type="string"/>
     <property name="info" type="string"/>
   </class> 

  <sql-query name="person1">
    <return alias="gb" class="PersonFo"/>
    SELECT id          as {gb.id},
           name        as {gb.name},
           info        as {gb.info}
    FROM   table
    WHERE  field1 = :param
  </sql-query>

  <sql-query name="person2">
    <return alias="gb" class="PersonFo"/>
    SELECT id          as {gb.id},
           second_name as {gb.name},
           whatever    as {gb.info}
    FROM   table
    WHERE  field2 = :param
  </sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the simplyfied hbm of what I do have.
In Java I am getting my data in this way, with the "getQueryName":

```
List<Person> myPersons =
    session.getNamedQuery("person1").setString("param", "important text").list();
```

Now I have to use views, instead of these querys. I know, I could simply write "SELECT xxx FROM view_person1" and "SELECT xxx FROM view_person2" into the sql-querys, but I would prefer to use something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="org.lwl.anlei.bl.model.imp">  

   <class name="PersonFo" 
    table="view_person1"
    entity-name="view_person1" >
     <id name="id" column="id" type="integer"/>     
     <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
     <property name="info" column="info" type="string"/>
   </class> 

   <class name="PersonFo" 
    table="view_person2"
    entity-name="view_person2" >
     <id name="id" column="id" type="integer"/>     
     <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
     <property name="info" column="info" type="string"/>
   </class> 

</hibernate-mapping>
```

In another example, I saw how to save data via hibernate this way.
[Map Two Identical tables ( same schema...) to same entity in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997950/map-two-identical-tables-same-schema-to-same-entity-in-hibernate)

They simply used:

```
_session.Save("view_person1", xxxx) 
_session.Save("view_person2", xxxx)
```

But, how do I QUERY data? Is there something like:

```
List<Person> myPersons =
    session.getNamedEntity("view_person2").list();
```

Help will be very appriciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `polymorphism="explicit"` to differentiate your named entities:

```
<class name="PersonFo" 
    table="view_person1"
    entity-name="view_person1" polymorphism="explicit" >
     <id name="id" column="id" type="integer"/>     
     <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
     <property name="info" column="info" type="string"/>
   </class> 

   <class name="PersonFo" 
    table="view_person2"
    entity-name="view_person2" >
     <id name="id" column="id" type="integer"/>     
     <property name="name" column="name" type="string"/>
     <property name="info" column="info" type="string"/>
   </class>
```

and query your named entities like below:

```
List list1 = session.createQuery("from view_person1").list();
List list2 = session.createQuery("from view_person2").list();
```

Comment: I'm gonna test that. Thanks in advance!