# How to map dynamically a single entity class to multiple tables?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

For various reasons related to existing legacy code and process, I would like to be able to use Hibernate to map a single entity class to different tables with the same structure. The tables are created dynamically at runtime from another known table. So for example, I would have the following class:

```
public class Item {

   private int id;
   private String label;
    ...
}
```

that would be mapped to say 3 different tables, `ITEM1`, `ITEM2` and `ITEM3` all having the same structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE ITEM[1|2|3] (
    NUMBER id PRIMARY KEY,
    VARCHAR label NOT NULL)
```

As said tables would be created at runtime according to some external configuration/condition.

I have reviewed the following questions on SO:

- [JPA, How to use the same class (entity) to map different tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997203/jpa-how-to-use-the-same-class-entity-to-map-different-tables)
- [How to map one class to different tables using hibernate/jpa annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505866/how-to-map-one-class-to-different-tables-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations)

and the proposed solution (subclassing) while possible is not really appealing. This would imply some black magic with dynamic class creation at runtime which I would rather avoid if I can.

From [this](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/blog/configuring-hibernate-programmatically-part-2) and [this](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/blog/configuring-hibernate-programmatically) blog posts I believe it is possible to create dynamic Hibernate mappings which would map a same entity to several tables.

Does anyone have more experiences implementing such dynamic mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case it matters, I'm the author of the blog posts you mentioned.

Let's break down your question in two:

1. is it possible to map the same class to multiple tables without subclassing?
2. is it possible to adjust the mapping at runtime to accomodate for new tables?

The answer to 1. is: yes, if you don't use annotations-based mapping and if you map the same class under different entity names. The second link you posted ([How to map one class to different tables using hibernate/jpa annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505866/how-to-map-one-class-to-different-tables-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations)) hints at that solution; you can do it with HBM files, or with programmatic configuration of course. You'll have to use the more verbose save(), update(), etc. overloads that allow to specify the entity name as an extra argument.

The answer to 2. is: yes and no; you can rebuild a whole new SessionFactory with the new mappings alongside the old ones (as we do in [Portofino](http://www.manydesigns.com/en/portofino)), but you cannot programmatically add new mappings to an existing SessionFactory. That means that at one point you'll have to close all existing sessions, dispose of the old SessionFactory, build the new one and start using it. In other words, yes, you can do it at runtime, but not seamlessly and concurrently with other uses of the same session factory. You can of course use multiple SessionFactories to split the mappings or to provide redundant mappings and handle gracious update schemes; it really depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the meantime, I started playing with the code following the general ideas of your blog post and managed to get 1. working, manually constructing the RootClass and mappings. I understand from point 2 and my own experiences that it is not possible to change the mappings with existing sessions, and that would probably be a bad idea anyway.

What I am trying to do now is build a Mappings from annotation, and tweak it *before* starting using it: This would dramatically reduce the amount of boilerplate to write. Did you try this in Portofino?

Comment: Very interesting! No, we didn't try that, because our input is our own xml model format which describes the structure of the db and the mappings. We do not map to annotated Java classes, but to hashmaps. However, we have thought several times about the possibility of allowing users to provide their own existing annotated classes or hbm files; it just hasn't been a priority yet.

Comment: I actually abandoned this path as I think we are trying to put square pegs in round holes: Hibernate and in general ORMs are useful to map *entities* and not as general purpose access layer to RDBMS. In our particular case, the requirement is best served using plain JDBC access without relying on ORM as we are basically using the DB as persistent storage for message queues, each consumer having its own queue mapped to a specific table. Thanks anyway for sharing your insights.

Comment: Well, that makes sense. We use Hibernate because our product is general-purpose and Hibernate provides a well-known API, and abstracts away a lot of tiny differences among database systems without precluding the possibility of using straight SQL when necessary. However, using Hibernate is not a solution without compromises, and for certain specific use cases, it can be much more of a hassle than good old JDBC. Have you considered myBatis? I don't know it first hand, but supposedly it is lower-level than Hibernate and friendlier towards pure SQL use, while still providing some OO benefits.

Comment: Yes, myBatis is a great tool, I used to work with it when it was called iBatis. I found it simple and efficient and would rather use it than Hibernate. But as you say, abstracting away most of the idiosyncrasies of various DB instances is a great benefit one gets from using Hibernate.