# Column mapping confusion

Tags: java, hibernate

A Table: NAME (varchar2), AGE (varchar2), ID_NO (varchar2)

B Table: NAME (varchar2), ADDRESS (varchar2)

And I got entity like this

```
@Entity
public calss A {
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="AGE")
    private String age;
    @Column(name="ID_NO")
    private String idNo;
    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    private String address;
}
```

When I excute this code:

```
session.createsqlQuery("SELECT * FROM A ").addEntity(A.clss).uniqueResult();
```

I got SQLException means address column not exists. And I don't want to put the `@Transient` to `Address` column, because I hope that I can use this entity to use B Table like this:

```
session.createsqlQuery("SELECT * FROM B ").addEntity(A.clss).uniqueResult();
```

How can I do to get this result successfuly?

Comment: Why not creating class `B`, that extends `A` and move field address on `B`?

Comment: You have 2 tables and an entity that represents neither table. What you need is a tutorial. Maybe even several tutorials.

Comment: I don't think that is allowed in Hibernate. You can check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505866/how-to-map-one-class-to-different-tables-using-hibernate-jpa-annotations).

Comment: @AlbertBos u're right , entends is the only way i can do, thanks~

Answer (score 0):

A short answer: you can't.

If you want to have this kind of things you should create class hierarchy (minimum without @Inheritance and other things I expect you to google on your own):

```
@Entity
public calss A {
    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="AGE")
    private String age;
    @Column(name="ID_NO")
    private String idNo;
}

@Entity
public class B extends A {
    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    private String address;
}
```

However, it won't work either as you should specify @Id column.

Comment: At first,I try to not generate lot of entity of tables,but it seems unavoidable

Comment: @C.Eason yes, it is. But what the purpose of this? By default you will have single table hierarchy so there is no need to create one more table. I don't see any other potentional doubts

Comment: In my old project , there are many complex sql  ,they don't use hibernate there, Now i want change query method to hibernate , but sql has join a lot table or too many  subquery ...Can u give me some advice about handle complex sql ?

Comment: @C. Eason the main advice that come to my mind is to be wise with joins then. beware things like `size(collection_name)` and all this stuff as it results in subqueries and can be performance cost. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3760901/5185646). also be careful with eager/lazy collections fetching as you can suddenly fetch entire collection that or forget to trigger lazy collection fetching. I guess mostly that's it that comes to my mind