# Make multiple tables of same entity dynamically

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to generate multiple tables out of a Java entity, the problem is that I need to generate them dynamically. Tables are numbered as `table_tenantId`

So, if I have multiple tenants I need to have a table per tenant. So If I have `3` tenants on my application I'll have:

```
table_1
table_2
table_3
```

But if I have `4` tenants, I'll need to have:

```
table_4
```

I've seen the answer stated here [JPA, How to use the same class (entity) to map different tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997203/jpa-how-to-use-the-same-class-entity-to-map-different-tables)

But I need to generate the class by myself.

Is there a way I can generate them dynamically?

////////////// Update //////////////

Columns:

```
private Long id;

private String filing_date; 

private String index_date;

private String filing_id_number;

private Byte state;

private Long documentalTypeInstance_id;

private Long documentalstructureinstance_id;

private Long parent_id;

private Long physicallocation_id;

private Long user_id;

private Long formdocument_id;

private String token_id;

private Boolean is_loaned;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is good idea? Like for me, it is more correct to have single table `tenant` with foreign key to `person` (1,2,3 etc) instead of having multiple tables for each one.

Comment: Could you provide column names of your tables, so we could try to help you.

Comment: I just added the column Names, thanks

Comment: @BorLaze It's because per tenant that table has millions of rows, and if every tenant is on the same table It can lead to a pretty bad performance issues

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-5-multitenancy