# How to switch tables in function of a JsonRPC parameters?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a single table with more than one million rows.

The thing is, I'm currently thinking in a way to split it regarding an external parameter. This will leave me with 5 smaller tables, but with the same columns. Therefore, is there a way to select one of the 5 tables without copy/pasting my previous table 5 times ? 
I work with jsonRPC.

My controller looks like this :

```
List<ObuDataDto> getOBUCustAnalytics(@JsonRpcParam(value = "obuCust") String obucust,
                                         @JsonRpcParam(value = "dateFrom") Double dateFrom,
                                         @JsonRpcParam(value = "dateTo") Double dateTo,
                                         @JsonRpcParam(value = "statisticsType") String[] statisticsType,
                                         @JsonRpcParam(value = "productId") Integer productId,
                                         @JsonRpcParam(value = "periodicity") String periodicity);
```

Depending on what's inside **periodicity**, I want to use a certain table. 
For now, my "too big" table looks like this :

```
@Table(name = "SAMPLE_DATA")
public class ObuDataDao {

    @Column(name = "OBU_ID")
    private String obuId;

    @Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
    private String customerId;

    @Column(name = "MONTH")
    private Integer month;

    @Column(name = "YEAR")
    private Integer year;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT", precision = 16, scale = 2)
    private Double amount;

    @Column(name = "DISTANCE")
    private Integer distance;

    @Column(name = "REGION")
    private Integer region;

    @Column(name = "BILLED")
    private Boolean billed;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
}
```

I could make 5 different versions of this class (all columns would be the same) and load the correct DAO regarding the periodicity value, but I think there is a more elegant way to do it (using @SecondaryTable maybe ?)
But I don't find anything about it

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997203/jpa-how-to-use-the-same-class-entity-to-map-different-tables).

The @MappedSuperClass did it for me.
But if any of you have a better suggestion, I'm all ears!